# Create an AD user from a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory

Running SQL Server 2008 (10.0.5520) - I have a trigger that is executed when a new record is added to the security table. I would like to extend this trigger, and create an entry in the AD system with a couple of the parameters from the insert.

Question is: can this be accomplished? If so, how?

It looks like a command line tool does exist:

[Technet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755811%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_5)

To create a contact named Jeff Hay in a top-level OU named Service Dept in the fabrikam.com domain, at a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:

```
dsadd contact "cn=Jeff Hay,ou=service dept,dc=fabrikam,dc=com"
```

Can this command line be executed from the trigger?

Comment: There's a lot of potential for security issues here and I would recommend AGAINST this sort of process. It means the SQL Service account has to have rights and you'll execute something like xp_cmdshell (which opens other holes).

What's the problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to create an AD account in this way?

Comment: Don't do this from within the trigger! The trigger should be **fast and nimble** - it should **not** do heavy lifting and time-consuming processing - and it should most definitely not be calling up an external resource that might take *quite some time* to respond! Instead - let your trigger make an entry into a "command" table, and have a **separate** process (T-SQL job or a little utility in any other language) read and interpret that command table and handle the actual creation of an AD user..

Comment: [Service Pack 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44278) is available for SQL Server 2008. You should patch your SP3 instance in addition to the fine advice from marc_s and mike fal

Comment: All great points - thank you     SP4 will not be added, as the software vendor does not support this program anymore.    The triggers are pigs currently, I will try the xp_cmdshell first, if that causes problems, i will roll it out to a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

What @Mike_Fal said. This is a huge gaping security hole. Not only does SQL need xp_cmdshell, but it will need Domain Admin rights. I also agree with the other sentiments around not using a trigger.

You can still tie it in with your existing process and make it database driven with the security table you are using. I'd probably write a separate, asynchronous process to read from the security table and add the AD users that way. This is a great job for PowerShell; connecting multiple systems and technologies.

Comment: Your recommendations are still based on the security hole(s) that you presented.   I will still need AD rights - and that appears to be your largest concern.   The trigger is already written, it is a pig, and the system is already perceived as very slow.   so a few more cycles will not be noticed.  The requirements have changed since the message was posted, so a different angle will need to be addressed.   but thank you for the posts!

Comment: Yes, the process that ultimately adds the user to AD needs domain admin rights. Building it in a trigger means that the SQL Service account needs domain admin rights. Big difference.

Comment: Regardless, it sounds like you are taking a different direction based on performance alone. Good luck with whatever solution you come up with!